# Is it correct to use "embrace" speaking about time?

Tags: collocation

Is it correct to say "Normally, a sprint embraces 2 weeks" ? 
Saying that I mean following "A regular sprint takes 2 weeks".

Comment: Which of the definitions of the verb "to embrace" do you think makes this correct?

Comment: I would say "include" (e.g. " Mathematics embraces arithmetic, algebra, and geometry.").

Comment: The problem with this is that a sprint doesn't include 2 weeks, it lasts 2 weeks. A week is a time frame, whereas a sprint more of a concept. Scrum embraces sprints, and months embrace weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the 7th entry at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/embrace?) might technically cover this usage of embrace, it sounds very awkward to a native speaker.

It is better to stick to the more accepted definitions of words, especially if you are communicating in a very technical group of people -- which I can assume you are based on your reference to agile sprints.

Comment: I don't think it does, not even technically. [OED definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/embrace) is *Include or contain (something) as a constituent part.* Is *week* a constituent part of *sprint*?